# Impossible to center vertically a box into a column

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am trying to align a Box in Jetpack which contain 2 icons in the vertical center of a column

The code for the Box parts is:

```
@Composable
    private fun passwordValidate() {
        Box(){
            Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_checkmark), contentDescription = "" )
            Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_xmark), contentDescription = "" ) 
        }
    }
```

The box is loaded in a column and donc as below:

```
Row(Modifier.padding(top = 20.dp)) {
                Column(modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(0.95f)) {
                    passwordField()
                }
                Column(modifier = Modifier          <------ Box part to be centered
                    .weight(0.05f),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
                    passwordValidate()
                }
            }
```

Right now it's look like this:

[image]

I intentionally have the red cross and green check image on top of the other one. because I only display one or the other, But I can't get them center in the column to be align with the EMAIL field

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Column` wraps content size. So its size is equal to the icon size, that's why `Column` arrangement doesn't work.

You could've pass `fillMaxHeight()` modifier to the `Column` to fix this, but actually you don't need a `Column` here, as you only have a single child(`Box`) inside. Pass a modifier as a parameter to `passwordValidate`:

```kotlin
@Composable
private fun passwordValidate(modifier: Modifier) {
    Box(modifier){
        Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_checkmark), contentDescription = "" )
        Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_xmark), contentDescription = "" )
    }
}
```

Then choose one of two:

1. Center all your `Row` children with `verticalAlignment` parameter:

```kotlin
Row(
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 20.dp)
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .weight(0.95f)
    ) {
        passwordField()
    }
    passwordValidate(
        Modifier
            .weight(0.05f)
    )
}
```

2. Center a specific child with `align` modifier.

```kotlin
passwordValidate(
    Modifier
        .weight(0.05f)
        .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
)
```